# How to debug assemble.io (ideally in Chrome Console)

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, gruntjs, assemble

I want to be able to capture and inspect all `Objects` that are being parsed by Handlebars in [Assemble.io](http://assemble.io/). Ideally in Google Chrome Developer Tools, just like I would inspect any other JavaScript. Any ideas?

Comment: Alright, so although it's not what I call _inspecting_, I managed to print all data using `grunt --verbose`. Still, an inspector would be nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Assemble's logging helpers](http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-logging.html) to dump objects to the console at build time.  This would take place on the server and not be reported to Chrome Dev Tools.

```html
<!-- Dump entire 'this' context -->
{{debug}}

<!-- Log string -->
{{log "hello, logging"}}
```